# asp.net obtain copy of rendered HTML

Tags: asp.net, html, html-email

I am creating a  website that will offer the option to email the user a copy of dynamic, code-behind, calculation-driven content on a final page of a website.  To send an email as of now I obtain the  calculation values from the model object again when the user clicks the button, writing all HTML tags by hand, sticking the model data in where needed.

My question is: is there any easier way to copy website output to an html formatted email?  I currently code an HTML email by hand and would like the ability to just get a copy of the rendered HTML, and possible modify it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (at least for me) is to actually create a webpage that does everything that you want it to do and then scrape it using `System.Net.WebClient` or `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`.

So you've got `Page1.aspx` which allows a person to select some things and submit a form and then you've got `Email1.aspx` which is the final output. When `Page1.aspx` is submitted use `WebClient` to download the contents of `Email1.aspx`, probably passing a querystring or some cookies over if needed. The user never "sees" `Email1.aspx` (except in their email of course), its just used behind the scenes.

The advantage of this approach is that you can test the HTML output without having to jump through SMTP hoops. In the `Email1.aspx` page you could also override the `OnRender()` method (I think that's the one, might have a different name possibly) if you need to modify the HTML. Or you could modify the HTML after downloading it. If you're performing the same basic HTML modifications you could subclass `System.Web.UI.Page`, implement your custom rendering and then have all of the emails inherit from your new subclass.

One thing that's important to remember, going down this route creates an HTTP request that's completely separate from the user's request, so things like session and cookies aren't passed over automatically, you'll need to find a way to do that on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the final ready-to-render html using the asp.net

```
Response.WriteFile("filename");
```

method